# ServiceBus over AMQP closes consumer

Tags: java, amqp, servicebus, azureservicebus, qpid

We have on-premise installation of ServiceBus and Java JMS QPID client 0.26. It seems that there is bug in SB - it sends END command to consumer when producer closes connection. Both producer and consumer must run on the same machine.

First start consumer that listens on a queue:

```
static void consumeFromQueueForStackOverflow(Connection connection, Context context)
        throws JMSException, NamingException, InterruptedException {
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    long RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS = 30000;

    try {
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("JBA_QUEUE");
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

        connection.start();

        int consumed = 0;
        while (true) {
            long startMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Message message = consumer.receive(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS);
            if (message != null) {
                consumed++;
                message.acknowledge();
                continue;
            }

            long durationMS = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMS;
            if (durationMS < RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS) {
                log.info(String.format(
                        "Connection is closed, timeout: %d[ms], waited: %s[ms] (consumed: %d)",
                        RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, durationMS, consumed));

                break;
            }

            log.info(String.format("Receive timeout, retrying (consumed: %d)", consumed));
            consumed = 0;
        }
    } finally {
        connection.stop();

        if(null != consumer)
            consumer.close();
        if(null != session)
            session.close();
    }
}
```

Then post 1 message to the queue:

```
static void publishToQueueForStackOverflow(Connection connection, Context context)
        throws JMSException, NamingException, InterruptedException {
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    try {
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("JBA_QUEUE");

        producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("My Message");
        producer.send(message);
    } finally {
        if(producer != null)
            producer.close();
        if(session != null)
            session.close();
    }

    log.info(String.format("Sent %d messages", count));
}
```

As soon as the producer process ends, the consumer will end too with waiting time smaller then timeout. The receive(timeout) method returns null prior to timeout expiration meaning (javadoc) "message consumer is concurrently closed". Alternatively you may see IllegalStateException: Closed during call to acknowledge().

Here is log from consumer. You can see that server sent unexpected End{} to client:

```
RECV[5671|0] : Open{containerId=087d0b7b8a8e4809a686f8b20d5376f5_GPRGXIT002,maxFrameSize=65536,channelMax=255,idleTimeOut=240000}
SEND[5671|0] : null
SEND[5671|0] : Begin{nextOutgoingId=0,incomingWindow=2048,outgoingWindow=2048,handleMax=4294967295}
SEND[5671|0] : Attach{name=IntegrationServiceBus/jba_testing_queue-> (48ff030e-c7be-42b2-9c22-4d0db13aec8f),handle=0,role=receiver,sndSettleMode=unsettled,rcvSettleMode=first,source=Source{address=IntegrationServiceBus/jba_testing_queue,durable=none,expiryPolicy=link-detach},target=Target{}}
RECV[5671|0] : Begin{remoteChannel=0,nextOutgoingId=1,incomingWindow=2048,outgoingWindow=2048,handleMax=7}
RECV[5671|0] : Attach{name=IntegrationServiceBus/jba_testing_queue-> (48ff030e-c7be-42b2-9c22-4d0db13aec8f),handle=0,role=sender,sndSettleMode=unsettled,rcvSettleMode=first,source=Source{address=IntegrationServiceBus/jba_testing_queue,durable=none,expiryPolicy=link-detach},target=Target{},initialDeliveryCount=0,maxMessageSize=262144,properties={com.microsoft:tracking-id=087d0b7b8a8e4809a686f8b20d5376f5_GPRGXIT002_BPRGXIT003;2411:54:55}}
SEND[5671|0] : Flow{nextIncomingId=1,incomingWindow=2048,nextOutgoingId=0,outgoingWindow=2048,handle=0,deliveryCount=0,linkCredit=100,drain=false,echo=false}
RECV[5671|0] : Transfer{handle=0,deliveryId=0,deliveryTag=\x84\xb8.\xf5\xda3\xafF\x89<J\x1bj\xda{<,messageFormat=0,more=false,batchable=true}
RECV[5671|0] : End{}
SEND[5671|0] : Detach{handle=0}
SEND[5671|0] : Disposition{role=receiver,first=0,last=0,settled=true,state=Released{}}
SEND[5671|0] : End{}
SEND[5671|0] : End{}
SEND[5671|0] : Close{}
RECV[5671|0] : Close{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug of the broker, the workround is to use sync_publish='all', for details see [ServiceBus over AMQP/QPID client closes consumer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ce261f33-8a72-44f0-bb60-af9f32e50194/servicebus-over-amqpqpid-client-closes-consumer?forum=servbus)